# передача файла и переход на страницу

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть простейший файлообменник
На странице index отображается перечень файлов. При нажатии на имя-ссылку файла  должна начинаться его закачка, счетчик закачек должен получить значение +1, пользователь должен остаться на этой же странице index. Сама вьюха:

```
    <div>
      <h1>Файлообменник на скорую руку</h1>

      <h2>Список файлов:</h2>
      <div id="stored_table">
        <table class="table table-border table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Файл</th>
              <th>Описание</th>
              <th>Закачек</th>
              <th>Загружен</th>
              <th>Размер</th>
              <th>Действие</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <%= render partial: 'stored', collection: @files %>

        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Партиал для списка файлов:

```
    <tr>
      <th><%= link_to stored.name, stored_file_path(stored), method: :put %></th>
      <th><%= stored.description %></th>
      <th><%= stored.downloads %></th>
      <th><%= stored.created_at %></th>
      <th><%= stored.size %> байт</th>
      <th>
        <%= link_to( fa_icon('window-close'), stored_file_path(stored),  method: :delete,
              style: "color:red", data: {confirm: 'Уверен что хочешь удалить?'}, remote: true ) %>      
      </th>
    </tr>
```

и сам контроллер:

```
    class StoredFilesController < ApplicationController

      # определяем скачиваемый файл
      before_action :set_file, only: [:update, :destroy]
      before_action :set_all_files #, only: [:index]

      def index
      end

      # ...

      def update
        # перед экшеном выполняется запрос текущего объекта в ф-ии set_file
        send_file Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', @file.name), filename: @file.name, type: 'Application/octet-stream' #disposition: "inline"
        @file.downloads += 1
        @file.save
        #render :index
        redirect_to root_path
      end

      def destroy
        File.delete(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', @file.name))
        @file.destroy
        redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Файл был удален'
      end

      private

      def file_params
        params.require(:new_file).permit(:description, :upload)
      end

      def set_file
        @file = StoredFile.find(params[:id])
      end

      def set_all_files
        @files = StoredFile.all.order('created_at DESC')
      end

    end
```

Для скачивания файла и обновления счетчика закачек используется экшен update.
В чем проблема: если в экшене update после закачки файла использую redirect_to root_path то строка send_file Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', @file.name), filename: @file.name, type: 'Application/octet-stream' #disposition: "inline" из контроллера не отрабатывает, загрузки файла не происходит, но счетчик закачки обновляется и происходит переход на стартовую страницу. Как решить эту проблему, что сделано не так?
ПС: в экшене :destroy, выполненномм тем же образом, удаление файла и переход на стартовую страницу происходят успешно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что вы пытаетесь отправить два разных ответа на один запрос, что в HTTP невозможно.

```
send_file Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', @file.name),
          filename: @file.name,
          type: 'Application/octet-stream'
          #disposition: "inline"
```

> 200 OK и содержимое файла

```
redirect_to root_path
```

> 302 Found и заголовок `Location: /`

По-хорошему, Rails должен бы швырнуть ошибку на такую ситуацию... но не швыряет.

---

Второй не нужен, т. к.

> пользователь должен остаться на этой же странице index

Зачем его перенаправлять туда, если он уже там? Если запрос по ссылке приводит к скачиванию файла, в браузере не происходит переход, т. к. некуда.

---

*PS: для скачивания предполагается `disposition: "attachment"`*

Comment: Согласен, оставил только запрос на скачку файла send_file....  Подскажите пожалуйста еще такой момент. Почему при скачке файла при экшене update выполняется два! get-запроса. Хочу прикрутить счетчик количества загрузок, но двойной запрос, и следующее за этим двойное обновление информации в БД будет накручивать счетчик в 2 раза больше необходимого.

Comment: @Yar-ua GET? У вас `update` же вызывается через PUT (или, это ж рельса, через PATCH). Не сходится. Берите отладчик.

Comment: Разобрался. Начал перерабатывать загрузку на новый экшен downloads и возникла путаница с методами GET и PATCH, Вопрос решен, спасибо за ответ!